# Problem handling cookies for Blazor Server using OpenID server (Keycloak)

Tags: cookies, server, blazor, nginx-reverse-proxy, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a baffling issue with cookie handling in a Blazor server app (.NET Core 6) using openid (Keycloak). Actually, more than a couple which are may or may not linked. It’s a typical (?) reverse proxy architecture:

- A central nginx receives queries for services like Jenkins, JypyterHub, SonarQube, Discourse etc. These are mapped through aliases in internal IPs where the nginx can access them. This nginx intercepts URL like: https://hub.domain.eu
- A reverse proxy which resolves to https://dsc.domain.eu. This forwards request to a Blazor app running in Kestrel in port 5001. Both Kestrel and nginx under SSL – required to get the websockets working.
  Some required background: the Blazor app is essentially a ‘hub’ where its various razor pages ‘host’ in iframe-like the above mentioned services. How it works: When the user asks for the root path (https://hub.domain.eu) it opens the root page of the Blazor app (/).
  The nav menu contains the links to razor pages which contain the iframes for the abovementioned services. For example:

[image]

The relative path is intercepted by the ‘central’ nginx which loads Jenkins. Everything is under the same Keycloak OpenID server. Note that everything works fine without the Blazor app.
Scenarios that cause the same problem

- Assume the user logins in my app using the login page of Keycloak (NOT the REST API) through redirection. Then proceeds to link and he is indeed logged in as well. The controls in the App change accordingly to indicate that the user is indeed authenticated. If you close the tab and open a new one, the Blazor app will act as if it’s not logged in while the other services (e.g Jenkins) will show the logged in user from before. When you press the Login link, you’ll be greeted with a 502 nginx error. If you clean the cookies from browser (or in private / stealth mode) everything works again. Or of you just log off e.g. from Jenkins.
- Assume that the user is now in a service such as Jenkins, SonarQube, etc. if you press F5 now you have two problems: you get a 404 Error but only on SOME services such as Sonarcube but not in others. This is a side problem for another post. The thing is that Blazor app appears not logged in again by pressing Back / Refresh
  The critical part of Program.cs looks like the following:

[image]
[image]

This class handles the login / logoff:

[image]

Side notes:

- SaveTokens = false still causes large header errors and results in empty token (shown in the above code with the Warning: Token received was null). I’m still able to obtain user details though from httpContext.
- No errors show up in the reverse proxy error.log and in Kestrel (all deployed in Linux)
- **MOST important**: if I copy-paste the failed login link (the one that produced the 502 error) to a "clean" browser, it works fine.
  There are lots of properties affecting the OpenID connect, it could also be an nginx issue but I’ve run out of ideas the last five days. The nginx config has been accommodated for large headers and websockets.

Any clues as to where I should at least focus my research to track the error??

Comment: What is the actual question? Quote a big question...

Comment: Apologies for the long post, the main question is this: assuming that nginx has appropriate configuration to handle large headers, is there any other reason that it would cause failure to send (?) the auth token back to the Blazor app so that it appears authenticated? I tried to describe the overal architecture and rational, hence the long post.

Comment: Are you using HTTPS? ASP.NET Core backend will split the cookie into multiple 4KB chunks if the cookie is to large.. however, I think its good to put the cookie on a diet and make sure it has a resonable size. if you really want to reduce the cookie size, then consider using a sessionstore, like https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/development/dotnet-development/using-auth-cookies-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: @ToreNestenius, Yes, I use HTTPS and yes size seem to be the issue. I went through again the central nginx logs (I don't have direct access to them) and apparently there's nothing wrong with the code I use for authentication - I don't know if it could be further optimized. The fact however that Blazor under both Keycloak and Identity Server somehow ends up with large headers, needs some fixing. I'll check the above link, it's what I was looking for since SaveToken=false doesn't do the job. Thanx for your insightful input!

Comment: I would first of all, look at what the browser sends to nginx and then what is sent from nginx to your services, and try to identify where information is lost. also, can you figure out, (perhaps using a tool like Fiddler) if you actually have large headers, and if so which header is large? perhaps post a sample header to the question?

Comment: With the above, I think you need to pinpoint where data is lost, do you use both keykloak and IdentityServer? I would first of all, host them on separate services/domains. I also would consider making one of them the primary token service that all services trust, and not both.

Answer (score 0):

The 502 error shows an error at *NGINX's side*. The reverse proxy had proper configuration but as it turned out, not the front one. Once we set the header size to suggested size, everything played out.